# try/finally - what is Python doing to the local namespace on an exception?

Tags: python, exception

This is not a duplicate of the various *why does a finally suppress my exception* questions.

Instead, I find that `finally`'s local variables are unexpected, but only in the case of an exception.  In that case, the exception disappears.

(This is on Python 3.8)

```
def test(divisor):
    print(f"\n\ntest({divisor=})")
    exc = None  #  always assigned!
    foo = 1

    print(f"  ante.{exc=}")

    try:
        _ = 1 / divisor
        print(f"  post.{exc=}")


    except (Exception,) as exc: 
        print(f"  except.{exc=}")
    else:
        print(f"  else.{exc=}")
    finally:
        print(f"  finally:{locals()=}")

        #at this point, it should be either None 
        #whatever was caught in the except clause
        print(f"  finally.{exc=}")

test(1)

test(0)
```

#### Output in the case of success - as expected:

```
test(divisor=1)
  ante.exc=None
  post.exc=None
  else.exc=None
  finally:locals()={'divisor': 1, 'exc': None, 'foo': 1, '_': 1.0}
  finally.exc=None
```

#### On an exception - UnboundLocalError

It looks like the local namespace had `exc` deleted and this causes an UnboundLocalError error.

I'd expect it to have the ZeroDivisionError.  At most, if `except` was defining a local scope for some reason, it could be still be `None`.  But it's just gone.

as if `del locals()["exc"]` had taken place.

```
test(divisor=0)
  ante.exc=None
  except.exc=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
  finally:locals()={'divisor': 0, 'foo': 1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_195_finally.py:27", in <module>
    test(0)
  File "test_195_finally.py:23", in test
    print(f"  finally.{exc=}")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exc' referenced before assignment
```

Binding `exc` to another variable shows that other variable is alive and well.

```
    except (Exception,) as exc: 
        exc2=exc
```

```
  finally:locals()={'divisor': 0, 'foo': 1, 'exc2': ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')}
```

Comment: That is really bizarre!  I wonder if this is a bug.  The documentation just says that the exception is assigned to the target.  https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Comment: @FrankYellin keep reading: "When an exception has been assigned using as target, it is cleared at the end of the except clause."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing [this thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue40728) about the same issue in the Python bug tracker, this is expected behavior

> [This] happens because we need to clean the exception variable outside the `except` block to avoid reference cycles. If you need the variable later, you need to do an assignment [..]

... which is also [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using `as target`, it is cleared at the end of the except clause.

So to keep the object reference, you need to store it in a differently named variable inside the `except` block.

Comment: Txs for finding this so quickly.  Doing just that, but I was really surprised at this behavior.  Makes sense if there's a behind the scene reason for garbage collection.  Still, unusual to find a bizarre edge case in Python.

Comment: Ditto.  Thanks for the explanation.  Very unexpected.

Comment: Unfortunately, reading the report, it sounds like they made a bug into a feature.

Comment: I know that Python isn't a block-scoped language, but it seems like making an, er, exception to that design and giving `except` clauses their own local scope would be less surprising than the _deletion of a preexisting local_.

Comment: @MarkReed  not really, no.  a) it would be a bigger wart than "just" nuking the variable and b) once we had a local scope/namespace to deal with it would an even bigger hassle to make `exc`s value visible to the finally clause so it would, on its own, achieve nothing.  I'd have qualify with `global exc` and even then I don't know if `global` would refer to the `test` function's scope (doubt it) or the script's full global scope (more likely).